# How do I split this list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to read elements from the second column in a .txt file, but no matter what I try, I can't.  The closest I've gotten is this format:

```
eigenlist = ['1    -58.44285   0.00000     3.000   0.000', 
             '2    -58.10455   0.33830     1.000   0.000',  
             '3    -57.57816   0.86469     0.000   1.000', 
             '4    -57.48698   0.95587     4.000   0.000', 
             '5    -56.90493   1.53792     5.000   0.000', 
             '6    -56.54419   1.89867     3.000   0.000']
```

I just want the second number in each element.

Comment: Please show the Python code and data used to generate the above array/list.

Comment: It would take me a long time to explain how I got it because I'm not all that apt with my coding lexicon, but for all intents and purposes, it really doesn't matter.  I have a list of strings which looks like that.  There are four spaces between the first and second number, three spaces between the second and third, five spaces between the third and fourth, and three spaces between the fourth and fifth.  That's all I can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

What about a list comprehension?

```
a = [float(s.split()[1]) for s in eigenlist]
```

Comment: I've tried this.  It doesn't work for some reason. :/ . It seems only to work when my elements are evenly spaced.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers cover the question fine. I just want to show that you can do this without using libraries.

```
>>> new_list = []
>>> for sublist in eigenlist:
...     new_list.append([s for s in sublist.split(' ') if s])
...
>>> new_list
[['1', '-58.44285', '0.00000', '3.000', '0.000'], ['2', '-58.10455', '0.33830', '1.000', '0.000'], ['3', '-57.57816', '0.86469', '0.000', '1.000'], ['4', '-57.48698', '0.95587', '4.000', '0.000'], ['5', '-56.90493', '1.53792', '5.000', '0.000'], ['6', '-56.54419', '1.89867', '3.000', '0.000']]
```

You can access each element simply now:

```
>>> for element in new_list:
...     print(element[1])
...
-58.44285
-58.10455
-57.57816
-57.48698
-56.90493
-56.54419
```